# C# dotnet console app to play mp3 on raspberry pi 3

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, .net-core, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I programmed a Telegram Bot via dotnet console application in C#.
It recognizes commands (like /hi) and it does actions...

A feature I want to integrate is the possibility to play songs when I send a number.
How can I play that .mp3 file via C# on my Raspberri Pi 3?
dotnet doesn't allow to use the "System.Media" lib...

I already tried searching for NuGet but I found nothing, I tried also searching on the web and searching some guides...

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using [omxplayer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/audio/) to play audio files?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado thanks for the suggestion. I solved using sox with the followind syntax:
`Process.Start("play",Path.Combine("files", "songs", song + ".mp3")); `

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found for the moment is https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetCoreAudio/ . The Nuget is working for MP3 files, but not for streams.

The project repo with doc is located here: https://github.com/mobiletechtracker/NetCoreAudio .

Comment: And this library calls on a raspberry (linux) the shell command
aplay -q

Answer (score 0):

A very dirty workaround is to pass the mp3 to the mpv media player (sleek small player that runs in the command line.

To do that, you have to install MPV first:

```sh
sudo apt install mpv -y
```

To start the player from within your .NET Core application, you can use the following code:

```cs
string PathToMp3File = "/home/pi/Test.mp3";

System.Diagnostics.Process PulseAudioStart = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("pactl", "info");
PulseAudioStart.WaitForExit();
if(PulseAudioStart.ExitCode != 0)
    throw new Exception($"Failed to initialize the PulseAudio daemon: {PulseAudioStart.ExitCode}");

System.Diagnostics.Process MpvStart = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mpv", $"--no-video --gapless-audio --volume=100.0 {PathToMp3File}");
MpvStart.WaitForExit();
if(MpvStart.ExitCode != 0)
    throw new Exception($"Failed to start the player: {MpvStart.ExitCode}");
```

You can also loop the file indefinitely (in that case you have to kill the process at some time) by using the command line argument `--loop=inf` for mpv

Enjoy!